# Why is this 少し followed by は?

Tags: particle-は

The 少し and は I'm referring to is from the lyrics of a song called [Don't you see!](http://www.kanzenshuu.com/lyrics/ja-dont_you_see/):

```
Don't you see!　願っても祈っても　奇跡　思い出
少しは気にかけて
```

I don't quite understand why the `少し` is followed by `は` because `少し` is not a noun and cannot be the main topic of a sentence for `は` to indicate.

Comment: The binding particle (係助詞)「は」 can be attached to 副詞: 「④叙述を強める。㋐〔格助詞・**副詞などに付いて** ...」([大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AF-597777#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)). Here the は is used in the sense of "at least" --> http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29438/does-%E3%81%AF-mean-at-least-in-this-sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here は is not used to make 少し the main topic of the sentence, but it is rather used to limit it, in the sense of:

> A little bit, but no more than that

Despite the fact 少し is an adverb, not a noun, it is perfectly acceptable to put a は after it, just as it would be safe to put は after words like いっぱい,ちょっと and すぐ.

The particle は can be used in many different contexts, here are a few more examples:

> 少しで**は**ありますが
>
> 彼はもう、長く**は**ない
>
> 死に**は**しない (しにゃしない）
>
> 僕が好きなの**は**、チョコレートだ
>
> 僕に**は**分かるよ
>
> 船で**は**行けない
>
> そうなると**は**思わなかった。

Comment: I suppose you mean "after"?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

「[少]{すこ}し」 is basically an adverb, but it also has a ***noun-like usage*** as well, which allows particles such as 「の」 and 「は」 to follow the word directly.  Any monolingual dictionary would mention this usage, too.

「少し**の**お[金]{かね}」 = "a small amount of money"

「少し**の**[我慢]{がまん}」 = "a little patience"

「少し」 in 「少し**は**」 is also used like a noun, but in this case, I would highly recommend that you remember 「少しは」 as a set phrase meaning "***in some degree***", "***in some small measure***", etc.

「少し**は**[気]{き}にかけて」, thus, means:

> "Please care a little about me.", "Please pay just a little attention to me.", etc.

Comment: Well, judging from the translation of this sentence "I still worry a little bit", it seems to me that the `少し` here is for modifying `気にかけて`, not for noun-like usage.