# How can I express "at least" in the sense of "it would be worse otherwise"?

Tags: grammar

How can I express "at least" in the sense of "it would be worse otherwise"? For example, "[It may be cold, but] at least it's not raining," or "[We're lost, but] at least we're together."

I sometimes want to make this kind of comment in Japanese but I haven't come across anything in my studies that seems equivalent.

Thank you!

Comment: How about ...が、少なくとも...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a very handy set phrase, 少なくとも【すくなくとも】.

少なくとも works when you talk about a quantity (you may already know this):

> - 少なくとも100万円は必要です。 We need at least 1 million yen.
> - 少なくとも5年は勉強しなさい。 You must study at least for 5 years.

And it also works when you talk about a situation that is better than something even worse:

> - 少なくとも雨は降っていない。 At least it's not raining.
> - 少なくとも何もしないよりはいい。 It's at least better than doing nothing.

As you may have noticed, the contrastive-は is often used with this expression. ([は on its own can have the meaning of "at least"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29438/5010).)

---

<sub>(I answered this question because you seem to be new to this site and it can be seen as a focused [phrase-requests](/questions/tagged/phrase-requests), but please always try to include your prior effort/research in your question. Otherwise, it may be [closed as an effortless bulk translation request](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se#799).)</sub>