# Is あの人たちだけ魔法を使える。 correct?

Tags: particle-だけ

> あの人たち**だけ**魔法を使える。
> Only they can use magic.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? To be specific, I am trying to figure out if the word 'dake' (だけ) is put correctly after "あの人たち".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あの人たちだけ魔法を使える is correct in casual speech, but it's not good as a formal sentence. Unlike も or すら, だけ doesn't replace が/は, so in formal settings you have to say either of:

- あの人たちだけは魔法を使える。
- あの人たちだけが魔法を使える。

See [this discussion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/66306/5010) regarding the difference between だけは and だけが.

Comment: 「[を]{●}使える」を聞くと、動詞の可能形に「を」を使うのは個人的にはどうか違和感がありますが、このパターンは現代広がっていますか、それとも昔から使われていますか。

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi [こういう質問](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/5010)があるのは知っていますが、個人的にはさほど大きな違いはない気もしています…。どのくらい昔からあるのかは分かりません…