# オンラインショップで買えるようにしてはいる

Tags: grammar

オンラインショップで買えるようにしてはいる

Would be grateful if someone could explain this part of the statement :

買えるようにしてはいる

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> オンラインショップで買えるようにしてはいる
>
> (literally) [Someone] has made it possible to buy it in the online shop, at least.
>
> (At least,) It's been made available in the online shop (although you cannot buy it here and now).

Here's the breakdown:

- 買う: to buy (it)
- 買**える**: can buy it
- 買える**ようにする**: to make sure one can buy it; to make it possible to buy it
- 買えるように**している**: have made it possible to buy it
- 買えるようにして**は**いる: have made it possible to buy it, at least

This [ようにする](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-you-ni-suru-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-meaning/) means "to make sure that ～", "to set up so that ～", etc. This は is a contrast marker, which [can be translated as "at least"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29438/5010). This している refers to the [continuation of the state](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010).

Comment: Thanks very much Naruto ! :)