# What does あった and かいは means in here

Tags: sentence

[image]

From what I understand 手に入れた権威をひけらかしたいだけの暴れん坊将軍につき合った can roughly translated into I accompanied a hooligan shogun that only knows to flaunt the power he obtained. What I don't understand is how かいは (which means something like faction based on yomiwa which is a japanese language app) and あった (which is past tense of to be exist) fits in this sentence.

Comment: It's かい(甲斐) + particle は + あった. Do you understand now? Also I don't know what you're reading but depending on context, 将軍 usually just means 'general', and not necessarily the military leaders of feudal Japan we mean when we say 'shogun' in English.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, but can I ask a other question? Why is the particle は is used here instead of particle が because most of the time i see they use かい(甲斐) + が particle + あった ( which means to be worth doing ) . Does it mean the same thing or the the usage of は change the meaning of the phrase. Also the reason I translate 将軍 to shogun because the manga the pic came from was set in the edo period but thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

- This かい is 甲斐 in kanji. It has several meanings, but here it refers to "value worth doing something" or "enough result/motivation (to justify some action)". 甲斐があった is a set phrase that roughly means "it was meaningful/worthy".
- This は is contrastive, i.e., [implies "at least"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29444/5010). For example, after watching a movie, 見た甲斐**が**あった sounds like the speaker is satisfied, but 見た甲斐**は**あった sounds like "It was not meaningless".

> ～につき合ったかいはあった。
> At least, it was worth it to deal with ～.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it