# Does で in this sentence 「日本の昔話は代表的なものだけで、２，３百はあります。」 mean that the noun before it is a tool for the proceding sentence?

Tags: nuances, particle-で

I would translate this sentence

> 日本の昔話は代表的なものだけで、２，３百はあります。

as "Japanese folktales has about 200, 300 as only representative of it". My question is does で after だけ mean that the noun before it acts as a tool for the proceding sentence?

My translation is awkward but I think that that's what the sentence mean. Is my translation correct? Or is there a better way to translate it and what is that better way? Also how do I factor "de" in translating this sentence?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your translation does seem awkward to me, so let's check what it means first:

- 日本の昔話は二、三百あります。
  There are 200 to 300 Japanese folktales.
- 日本の昔話は二、三百**は**あります。
  There are **at least** 200 or 300 Japanese folktales.
- 日本の昔話は**代表的なものだけで**二、三百はあります。
  **Counting only the major ones**, there are at least 200 or 300 Japanese folktales.

The particle で after 代表的なものだけ is a **scope/condition** marker rather than a method marker. It marks the condition for the following expression to hold true. Similar examples include:

- **合計で**30人います。
  There are 30 people **in total**.
- **最大で**3万円かかります。
  It will cost **up to** 30,000 yen.
- **追加で**50個注文しました。
  I ordered **additional** 50 units.
- **今日だけで**単語を100個覚えました。
  **Today alone**, I learned 100 words.
- **ある意味で**興味深い。
  It's interesting **in one sense**.

Unfortunately, there is no one-size-fits-all English expression that corresponds to this type of で, so you'll need to get used to them individually.

Comment: Didn't know that は with numbers meant "**at least**". Are you able to use も as well (and what does it mean)?

Comment: @firuvi See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29438/5010). You can use も but the meaning would be changed. "二、三百もある" means "there are as many as 200-300 folktales".

Comment: @RommelBagasina it's redundant, but mentally adding a の中{なか} before this scope で can help to interiorize its meaning: 日本の昔話は代表的なものだけの中{なか}で二、三百はあります。